# codesignal remove palindrome prefixes and return string

Tags: python, palindrome, prefix

You are given a string s. Consider the following algorithm applied to this string:

Take all the prefixes of the string, and choose the longest palindrome between them.
If this chosen prefix contains at least two characters, cut this prefix from s and go back to the first step with the updated string. Otherwise, end the algorithm with the current string s as a result.

I am faling this testcase "bbabbaabaabbbbb". I am returning "b" instead of "". I think the correct answer is "b". But I must be missing something.

```
def find(s):
        maxLen=0
        R=0
        L=0
        pref=""
        for p in range(len(s)):
            l=p-1
            r=p+1
            while l>-1 and r<len(s) and s[r]==s[l]:
                if r-l+1>maxLen:
                    maxLen=r-l+1
                    R=r
                    L=l
                l-=1
                r+=1
            l=p
            r=p+1
                
            while l>-1 and r<len(s) and s[r]==s[l]:
                if r-l+1>maxLen:
                    maxLen=r-l+1
                    R=r
                    L=l
                l-=1
                r+=1
        
        if R-L+1>1:
            
            
            return find(s[:L]+s[R+1:])
            # return s[:L]+s[R+1:]
        else:
           
            return s
    x=find(s)

    if x:
        return x
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: When visually scanning the sample string, the longest embedded substring that is a palindrome is "bbaabaabb".  Is that what your program is supposed to find?

Comment: Yes, and then remove it from the string if it's more than two characters

Comment: Finally understood my problem, I was looking for the longest substring rather than logest prefix

Answer (score 0):

Now that I had your answer and that I was interpreting the desired outcome correctly, I tried to see if I could make a go of getting your code to work.  Try as I might, I just could not work out a solution, so I took a step back to determine the course of action that a program would need to parse and find the longest palindrome in a given character string.  Basically, what would need to be done is:

- First, define a function that would evaluate a string of characters to see if it is a palindrome and return a "True/False" value.
- Input a string and then starting from the first character to the last character, see if a palindrome of two or more characters is found.
- Repeat the process, going from the second character to the end, then third character to the end, and so forth, check these substrings for a palindrome.
- As a palindrome is found, check its length against any previously found palindromes to see if it is the longest, and if so store the string value.
- Finally, print out the longest palindrome found.

With that, here is a refactored version of code to perform those steps.

```
def IsPalindrome(text):                         # Simple function to test a string to see if it's a palindrome
    result = True
    x = len(text)
    
    for i in range(x):
        if text[i] != text[x - i - 1]:
            result = False
            break

    return result

def main():
    test = input("Enter a string: ")            # Acquire the string to evaluate
    current = ""                                # Initialize a string that will hold the largest found palindrome
    lenga = len(test)

    for ii in range(lenga):                     # Starting with the complete string, test for the longest palindrome
        subs = test[ii:lenga]                   # Keep decrementing to acquire a shorter substring to test left to right
        lengb = len(subs)

        for xx in range(1, lengb + 1):          # Begin looking for the longest palindrome in each substring
            subx = subs[:xx]
            if (IsPalindrome(subx)):
                if(len(subx) > len(current)):   # Compare and store the longest found palindrome
                    current = subx

    print("The longest palindrome found is:", current)
    
main()
```

The key is the function that checks a string to see if it's a palindrome.  This is just one of many variations to do that.  Following is the subsequent parsing of the entered string value and storage of the largest found palindrome.  Testing this code out with your example string results in the following output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/LongPal$ python3 LongPal.py
Enter a string: bbabbaabaabbbbb
The longest palindrome found is: bbaabaabb
```

I hope I haven't done your homework for you, but have given you some initial clues for problem solving.